# kinetic energy of flowing fluid

Tags: fluid-dynamics, collision

When a quantity of fluid (let's say equal to volumetric flow rate Litre/s) collides during a second with an object, do all the molecules of this quantity collides with it? I am asking this question because the collision between 2 solids only happens between the molecules of their surface but the energy transmitted in collision is equal to 1/2mv2 where m is the mass of the total molecules but in a fluid is it the same? If not all the molecules collide with the solid (like in a collision between 2 solids), does the energy 1/2mv2 of the fluid will be transmitted? That means : it does not depend on the number of molecules that collide like between 2 solids?

Comment: When two cars collide, do all the molecules of the cars collide with each other?

Comment: no but in fluid does the amount of molecules collided make the energy transfered higher? or it does not depend?

Comment: How much energy is transferred depends on a lot of things. Fluids being completely deformable, when a fluid 'blob' hits a solid object change in momentum of different parts of the 'blob' affects how much energy transfer takes place, even though the kin. energy contained in the 'blob' may well be *exactly* the same as contained in a solid object. A soft snowball will do less damage than a ball of hard steel of the same kinetic energy.